# Deserialize XML throws an error

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to deserialize xml by using the followng code

```
var reader = new StringReader(uri);
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(livescore));
var livescores = (livescore)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

where as 'fileToRead' containing a url from where to load xml. But when it tires to deserialize, throws an error

```
Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1
```

I looked a no of post related to this issue, but none of the trick working for me. Any suggestion please?

If I copy the response into a file and read using `StreamReader` instead of `StringReader`, it works fine. Not sure, what changes I need to make

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795167/xml-loaddata-data-at-the-root-level-is-invalid-line-1-position-1

Comment: I am not reading xml from string or a file. Could you please mention, how that work in my case?

Comment: @user3339997 That's about a completely different API.

Comment: Could you please tell me about that API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`StringReader` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.stringreader(v=vs.110).aspx) accepts the string that it shall process, *not* a file name. Most likely, you are passing in a file name, which in turn the `XmlSerializer` tries to parse as XML — not the *contents* of the file but its *name*. (**UPDATE:** It's irrelevant whether it's a file name or an URI, the principle is the same.)

Instead, use a `StreamReader` which accepts a file name in [its constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ke0fzy(v=vs.110).aspx). Then the rest of your code should work:

```
var reader = new StreamReader(fileToRead);
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(livescore));
var livescores = (livescore)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Also note you should wrap your code into `using` statements properly to manage your resources properly:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileToRead))
{
    … deserialization code goes here …
}
```

**UPDATE** Use [`WebRequest.Create(uri)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw00b1dc(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a reader, the retrieve the response using [`GetResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getresponse(v=vs.110).aspx). There's a complete example in MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.WebRequest(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Please see the updated question. My bad I forgot to change the parameter name. I want to read xml from http address. Reading from the file works for me. Now I want to read feed.

Comment: That depends on the type of the URI. You can use the `WebRequest` class and its [`Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw00b1dc(v=vs.110).aspx) method which handles several types of URI.

Comment: You could also use `XmlReader.Create` which says it takes a URI in the documentation. Then there is another overload of Deserialize that takes an XmlReader.

Comment: After using XmlReader, when it tries to deserialize throws an error: {"'', hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1."}

Comment: You should learn to debug your code. Most likely, it's still the same issue: you are confusing a *name / URI* and the actual XML *content*. If you can't figure it out, update or post another question.

Comment: OK. That's because when I used XmlReader.Create. After I moved to WebRequest, it does not work either unit I uncompress the xml with GzipStream. Anyway, Thanks for your help and pointing me into right direction.