# Load XML String having escape characters

Tags: c#, memorystream, xmlwriter

I have a string `sMediaXML` which resembles an XML fragment, except for the fact that it contains backslash escape characters. I am unable to load this string into an `XmlDocument` enabling me to check and see if an element exists etc... I need to keep the string format exactly as you see below because other code will be depending on it later on.

```
// sMediaXML = "<media><cd><burned value=\"true\" /></cd><vinyl><pressed value=\"true\" /></vinyl></media>"   

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

namespace xmlWriter_Console
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
            settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
            settings.CloseOutput = false;

            MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream();

            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(strm, settings))
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("media");
                writer.WriteStartElement("cd");
                writer.WriteStartElement("burned");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("value", "true");
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteStartElement("vinyl");
                writer.WriteStartElement("pressed");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("value", "true");
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }

            string sMediaXML = Encoding.UTF8.GetString((strm).ToArray());
            Boolean bNodeExists;

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(sMediaXML);

            if (xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/media/digital/@value").Value != null)
            {
                bNodeExists = true;
            }
            else
            {
                bNodeExists = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: " I am unable to load this string into an XmlDocument enabling me to check and see if an element exists etc..." - why? what happens? what is the actual issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document;
settings.CloseOutput = false;

MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream();

using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(strm, settings))
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("media");
    writer.WriteStartElement("cd");
    writer.WriteStartElement("burned");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("value", "true");
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteStartElement("vinyl");
    writer.WriteStartElement("pressed");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("value", "true");
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}

string sMediaXML = Encoding.UTF8.GetString((strm).ToArray());
Boolean bNodeExists;
string _byteOrderMarkUtf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());
if (sMediaXML.StartsWith(_byteOrderMarkUtf8))
{
    sMediaXML = sMediaXML.Remove(0, _byteOrderMarkUtf8.Length);
}
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(sMediaXML);

if (xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/media/cd/burned/@value").Value != null)
{
    bNodeExists = true;
}
else
{
    bNodeExists = false;
}
```

1. If you have an XML string that you want to load into a `XDocument` you should use `LoadXml` method not `Load`. The `Load` method is used when loading directly from disk or streams.
2. The `XDocument` can not parse the xml string because it contains the UTF-8 byte specifying the order. More information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getpreamble(v=vs.110).aspx). There is an other option for this to work, to view it, check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795167/xml-loaddata-data-at-the-root-level-is-invalid-line-1-position-1).
3. The `XPath` query you have won't work anyway because you don't have any "digital" elements defined.