# C# xml to object (deserialization)

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xml-deserialization

**XML to C# object returning error:**

> Error is :  Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

How to deserialize xml string to c# object?

Here is my XML:

```
<MSGIDRETURN>
    <VERSION>1.0</VERSION>
    <MSGID_LIST>
        <MSGID>Test1234567</MSGID>
    </MSGID_LIST>
</MSGIDRETURN>
```

Here is my C# Classes:

```
[XmlRoot("MSGIDRETURN")]
public class MSGIDRETURN
{
    [XmlElement("VERSION")]
    public string Version { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("MSGID_LIST")]
    public MSGID_LIST MsgIdList { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
public class MSGID_LIST
{
    [XmlElement("MSGID")]
    public List<string> MsgId { get; set; }
}
```

And Deserialization Code :

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MSGIDRETURN));
        StringReader rdr = new StringReader(inputString.Trim());
        MSGIDRETURN resultingMessage = (MSGIDRETURN)serializer.Deserialize(rdr);
```

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/17795167/22683

Comment: Just tried your solution, with string instead of input and it's working. What is your inputString? Is that file or something else?

Comment: @zholinho thank you for answer. inputString has some invalid character like \" . now it is working. I edit my string as you write in testData and it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried your solution, with string instead of input and it's working.
What is your **inputString**? Is that file or something else?

```
string testData = @"<MSGIDRETURN>
                        <VERSION>1.0</VERSION>
                        <MSGID_LIST>
                            <MSGID>Test1234567</MSGID>
                        </MSGID_LIST>
                     </MSGIDRETURN>";

 XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MSGIDRETURN));
 StringReader rdr = new StringReader(testData.Trim());
 MSGIDRETURN resultingMessage = (MSGIDRETURN)serializer.Deserialize(rdr);
```