# Getting Error in Telerik Reporting, showing unable to get report parameters. An error has occurred

Tags: asp.net, telerik, reporting, telerik-reporting

I have completely stacked on one issue in **Telerik Reporting R3 2020**. I am working on **HTML5 Report Viewer** using Telerik Custom Resolver. Everything is going fine, successfully getting the results from DB. However, getting an error when trying to bind the data in **xmlReportSource** at the **CustomReportSourceResolver**. Following is my source codes. Hope, it will be helpful to understand. I have already go for Telerik Reporting documentations several times, but can't find any solution yet.

**Error:**
**Unable to get report parameters.
An error has occurred.
Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.**

[image]

**ReportsController**

```
public class ReportsController : ReportsControllerBase
    {

        static ReportServiceConfiguration configurationInstance;

        static ReportsController()
        {
            var resolver = new UriReportSourceResolver(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Reports"))
                .AddFallbackResolver(new TypeReportSourceResolver()
                    .AddFallbackResolver(new CustomReportSourceResolver()));

            configurationInstance = new ReportServiceConfiguration
            {
                HostAppId = "Application1",
                ReportSourceResolver = resolver,
                Storage = new Telerik.Reporting.Cache.File.FileStorage(),
            };
        }

        public ReportsController()
        {
            this.ReportServiceConfiguration = configurationInstance;
        }
    }
```

**CustomReportSourceResolver**

```
public Telerik.Reporting.ReportSource Resolve(string reportId, OperationOrigin operationOrigin, IDictionary<string, object> currentParameterValues)
        {
            var cmdText = "SELECT Definition FROM Reports WHERE ID = @ReportId";

            var reportXml = string.Empty;
            using (var conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(@"server=(local);database=REPORTS;integrated security=true;"))
            {
                var command = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(cmdText, conn);
                command.Parameters.Add("@ReportId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
                command.Parameters["@ReportId"].Value = reportId;

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    reportXml = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(reportXml))
            {
                throw new System.Exception("Unable to load a report with the specified ID: " + reportId);
            }

            return new Telerik.Reporting.XmlReportSource { Xml = reportXml };
        }
```

**HTML5 Viwer**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Telerik HTML5 Report Viewer</title>
   
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.114/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.1.114/styles/kendo.blueopal.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!--If Kendo is used it should be added before the report viewer.-->
    <script src="/api/reports/resources/js/telerikReportViewer-14.2.20.916.min.js/"></script>

    <style>
        #reportViewer1 {
            position: absolute;
            left: 5px;
            right: 5px;
            top: 5px;
            bottom: 5px;
            overflow: hidden;
            font-family: Verdana, Arial;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="reportViewer1">
        loading...
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#reportViewer1")
                .telerik_ReportViewer({
                    serviceUrl: "/api/reports",

                    reportSource: {
                        report: 1
                    },

                    viewMode: telerikReportViewer.ViewModes.INTERACTIVE,

                    scaleMode: telerikReportViewer.ScaleModes.SPECIFIC,

                    scale: 1.0,
                    enableAccessibility: true,

                    sendEmail: { enabled: false },

                    ready: function () {
                    },
                });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the report definition you're getting use any parameters? You're setting the `Xml` property in `XmlReportSource`, but you haven't added any parameters for the report to use.

Comment: No. I just need to load the TestReport.trdp to my HTML report viewer. Ops, I didn't call the TestReport.trdp from any where! Can you please tell me where should I put the TestReport.trdp name? I am following this: https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/telerik-reporting-rest-custom-report-resolver

Comment: Ok if you have a .trdp file you can set a path to that file in the viewer's reportSource. [Here](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/html5-report-viewer-jquery-fn-telerik-reportviewer#examples) is an exemple from Telerik that shows how to set the path.

Comment: Ok. But, if I use reportSource: { report: "TestReport.trdp" }, HTML Viewer is loading the trdp file. But, can not call the reportResolver and that is why can not bind the data from database. reportResolver is only calling hen I write reportSource: { report: 1 }.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this question: [xml.LoadData - Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795167/xml-loaddata-data-at-the-root-level-is-invalid-line-1-position-1)

In my case, there was a hidden BOM in the XML string.

Per the other answer, this bit stripped the invalid character.

```
string _byteOrderMarkUtf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());
if (xml.StartsWith(_byteOrderMarkUtf8))
{
xml = xml.Remove(0, _byteOrderMarkUtf8.Length);
```

}