# Find matching string from a long string, C#

Tags: c#, .net

If  `string xml;`  contains following xml as text

```
<table xmlns="http://www.mynamespace.org/standard">
  <tr>
    <td>Apples</td>
    <td>Bananas</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to find the value of **xmlns** attribute from this string. In this example, I want to find a value like

```
string namespace =?
```

and namespace should contain value "http://www.mynamespace.org/standard".

How this can be found effectively?

Comment: Have you tried any xml parser?

Comment: XML works with nodes, not strings. If you use any XML parser you'll be able to check a node's namespace. Whether you use XmlSerializer, XmlDocument, XmlReader or XDocument, you can check a node's namespace

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos minutiae: `XmlSerializer` really wouldn't be a good choice here - it is fussy about namespaces being known in advance and matching, unless you *basically* tell it to deserialize into an `XmlElement` or something

Comment: I have tried but sometimes in XML file I am getting such text(format/encoding of text) that, and  XDocument.Parse gives the following error
 "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."
going further, the solution provided here does not always work with different files

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795167/xml-loaddata-data-at-the-root-level-is-invalid-line-1-position-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cs
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var ns = doc.Root.Name.Namespace;
```

or similar with `XmlDocument`, `XmlReader`, etc. If you *only* care about the root element, `XmlReader` will be the most efficient (as you can stop reading at the first node). For example:

```cs
using var reader = XmlReader.Create(source);
reader.MoveToContent();
var ns = reader.NamespaceURI;
```

(if your xml is in a `string`, then `using var source = new StringReader(xml);` can help with that)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Marc, I have implemented the same but sometimes in XML file I am getting such text(format/encoding of text) that, and  XDocument.Parse gives the following error
 "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."
going further, the solution provided here does not always work with different files

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795167/xml-loaddata-data-at-the-root-level-is-invalid-line-1-position-1

Comment: @GurpreetKailey It should, though. Of course, your input files may be broken (i.e. invalid xml, not well-formed ... or sometimes even BOMs can hurt).

Comment: @GurpreetKailey honestly, I'm going to assume that the framework is right, and that your xml is in fact: broken. Do you have an example of a broken file? Note: as noted in question you link to, the underlying case could be a BOM in the wrong place; *most* of the time, BOMs should be handled entirely silently and automatically; it may also help to specify the encoding explicitly when opening the file

Comment: Is it possible to find it using regular expression?

Comment: @GurpreetKailey if it is a BOM? no, not really; a BOM isn't part of the payload, and a regex looks at a payload; and to load the payload (correctly) you need to use the right encoding; if that isn't currently working, you need to fix *that*, not try to hack around data that is by definition *already corrupt* (at least partially)