# XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1

Tags: asp.net, .net, xml, xslt, doctype

My XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE task  "sdlGeneralTask.dtd"[]>
<task id="1234" xml:lang="en">
  <title id="12345">For Validation Test</title>
  <taskbody cid="345">
    <steps id="1263">
      <step cid="324">
        <cmd>Test operation for validation.</cmd>
      </step>
    </steps>
  </taskbody>
</task>
```

MY XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>   
<html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">    
    <body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#FFFFFF">    
        <xsl:for-each select="task">    
            <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">    
                <span style="font-weight:bold">    
                    <xsl:value-of select="node"/>    
                </span>
            </div>    
             
        </xsl:for-each>    
    </body>    
</html>
```

i am using below code to transform xml to html, as i need html string as output.but i am getting error "XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."

```
public static string TransformXMLToHTML(string inputXml, string xsltString)
        {
            XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsltString)))
            {
                transform.Load(reader); //getting error at this point
            }
            StringWriter results = new StringWriter();
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(inputXml)))
            {
                transform.Transform(reader, null, results);
            }
            return results.ToString();
        }
```

can anyone please help what is wrong at line 1 in my xslt or xml

Comment: Please change xml Declaration following:-

<!DOCTYPE task SYSTEM "dlGeneralTask.dtd">

Comment: i replaced xml declaration but still same error

Comment: ystem.Xml.Xsl.XslLoadException
  HResult=0x80131942
  Message=XSLT compile error.
  Source=ComparisionTool
  StackTrace:
   at ComparisionTool.XmlCompare.TransformXMLToHTML(String inputXml, String xsltString) in C:\Users\x\Documents\ComparisionTool\ComparisionTool\ComparisionTool\XmlCompare.aspx.cs:line 45
   at ComparisionTool.XmlCompare.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\x\Documents\ComparisionTool\ComparisionTool\ComparisionTool\XmlCompare.aspx.cs:line 31

Inner Exception 1:
XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Comment: last time please remove Declaration DOCTYPE

Comment: Please check it

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795167/xml-loaddata-data-at-the-root-level-is-invalid-line-1-position-1

Comment: wow now i got the result , Awesome !!

Comment: your problem solve it

Comment: Thanks for all your help on it Ajeet!! Great help ! if you have any idea on how to pass the result string to aspx page string please share me any link or suggest me

Comment: i'm not asp.net programmer

Comment: Thanks Ajeet i will find it out ,and  sorry to bother again  i am getting only the tile as output  , i also need all strings inside  taskbody , is it possible?

Comment: what u exact output get please tell

Comment: <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#FFFFFF">
    <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
      <span style="font-weight:bold">Test topic new</span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: for now i only get title as an output but i also need to display all elements which are inside taskbody element

Comment: <xsl:value-of select="node()"/>
                    <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="taskbody"/>
                    </xsl:copy>

Comment: It worked :) Thank you so much for your quick responses , i appreciate your help on it .. have a wonderful day Ajeet!!!

Comment: Hi Ajeet,   Can we split the content node by node using xslt , i am getting the html output correctly and as it is a string i am getting the content all together like this "Test topic newTest topic newI am a new picture againI must look how to cause a picturePlease do not over write the picture Hello second step"