# How to get the Configuration App Settings file in MAUI iOS

Tags: configuration, maui

I am converting my Xamarin Forms Application to .NET MAUI.

In existing application I am using below code which is using Xamarin.iOS to fetch the config file(App.config) which is in xml format and has app settings

```
public string Path
        {
            get
            {
                try
                {
                    return System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile;
                }
                catch
                {
                    throw new FileNotFoundException(@"File not found.");
                }
            }
        }
```

But the same code doesn't work in MAUI

I tried below approach but File.OpenRead(Path) is throwing error "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1"
App.config file is added in path Projectname/Platforms/iOS/App.config

```
public string Path
        {
            get
            {
                try
                {
                    string configPath = string.Empty;
                    configPath = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location + ".config";
                    AppDomain domain = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
                    configPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(domain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase, domain.FriendlyName + ".config");
                    return configPath;
                }
                catch
                {
                    throw new FileNotFoundException(@"File not found.");
                }
            }
        }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: *Which line of code* throws that error?

Comment: File.OpenRead(Path) is throwing the error

Comment: That is an `XML` error message, not a `System.IO.File.OpenRead` error message. What is the value of `Path`? Show several lines of code before and after `File.OpenRead`. Most importantly, show code that is trying to work with xml. Maybe it found an empty file? But that still would fail on a different line. Sounds like your source file isn't identical to what is executing - Rebuild Solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since the value of Path could be obtained, you could manually checked the content to see if it is the one you want.

From the thrown error *"Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1"*, it seems something wrong with xml data load. Some issues similar to this question indicated that it may due to BOM character, take a look at this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795167/xml-loaddata-data-at-the-root-level-is-invalid-line-1-position-1).

Actually we could use **appsettings.json** as an alternative, see this [App Configuration Settings in .NET MAUI](https://montemagno.com/dotnet-maui-appsettings-json-configuration/) and [github project](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/dotnet-maui-configuration/tree/master/MauiApp27). It's really easy  to read app config in this way.